# Incorrect image size in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am using unsorted list to display image with the a tag to implement lightbox on each images to see a bigger version of the image.
On Mozilla Firefox, Google chrome and Opera the image are displayed with the correct size but in Internet Explorer they are smaller.

W3C Validator reports 0 errors and I declared the Doctype.

Here is the source code of the web page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Makeup Artist - Hair Stylist | Natalie Bennet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mouseoverscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js" ></script>
<div id="border"></div>
<div id="hide"></div>
<div id="header" align="center">
<div id="logo" align="center">
<img src="images/makeup-artist-hair-stylist.jpg" alt="Natalie Bennett" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer-arrow previous" style="left:1%; position:fixed;">
<img src="images/left-arrow-out.png"
onmouseover="this.src='images/arrow-left-on.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='images/left-arrow-out.png'" alt="previous" /></div>
<div class="galleryWrapper">
<ul class="galleryItems" style="list-style-type:none;">
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/Sofia_1.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/Sofia_1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/Sofia_2.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/Sofia_2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/Sofia_3.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/Sofia_3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/Sofia_4a.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/Sofia_4a.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/Sofia_4b.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/Sofia_4b.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/Sofia_4.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/Sofia_4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/Sofia_5.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/Sofia_5.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/Andro_1.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/Andro_1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/Andro_2.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/Andro_2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/Andro_3.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/Andro_3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/Andro_4.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/Andro_4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
[...]
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/T1.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/T1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/portfolio/big/T2.jpg"><img class="portfolio" src="images/portfolio/T2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="footer-arrow next" style="left:96.5%; position:fixed;">
<img src="images/right-arrow-out.png"
onmouseover="this.src='images/arrow-right-on.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='images/right-arrow-out.png'" alt="next" /></div>
<div id="footer">
<div id="site-navigation" align="center">
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:closeThenNavigate('about.php')">About</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:closeThenNavigate('backstage.php')">Backstage</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:closeThenNavigate('contact.php')">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="footer-menu">
</div>
<div id="copyright">
&copy; Natalie Bennett 2012
</div>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.galleryItems a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
openFooter();
var menuopen = false;
function openFooter(){
$('#footer').animate({
height: 40,
bottom:0
}, 750, 'linear');

}

function closeFooter(){
$('#footer').animate({
height: 20,
bottom:0
}, 750, 'linear');

$('#footer-button').css("backgroundPosition","center 0px");
}

var currentImage = 0;

function closeThenNavigate(url)
{
 $('#footer').animate({
 height: 20,
bottom:0
}, 750, 'linear', function() {
  window.location.href=url+"?i="+currentImage;
});
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

And here is the CSS for the images :

```
img {
    border:none;
}
ul{
    padding:0px;
}
.galleryWrapper{
    top:6%; 
    left:0px; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
    display:inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.galleryItems li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float:left;
}

.portfolio{   
    widht:80%;
    height:88%;
    margin: 6px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:250px;;
}
```

Do you know why they are smaller in IE ?

Edit, forgot the link : http://www.zackdibe.com/final/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed use pixels instead of % or live with it. IE7/8 uses quite a lot bigger area for the addressbar (bigger then for example Chrome or FF), so the viewable area is smaller, from where the percentage is calculated.

Comment: But I would like to get the same ratio on every Viewport, if I use px instead of % I'll have to scroll when the viewport will be smaller, isn't it ?

Comment: Well yeah, I'd recommend to leave it like this (can't really see the problem since I've only got IE9 in which the adressbar area is smaller). It's not a big deal, certainly not noticable by visitors. If you make a point of this, you also should of people with different screen sizes :P. Anyway, I do see two rows of images in my FF and IE (Chrome is fine), fixable by upping the width on "galleryItems".

Comment: Alright, I'll keep it like that so. Yeah I noticed the two rows on the bigger Viewport, I used a margin-bottom but it don't seems to be enough. Like you advised me, I putted a width of 100% for "galleryItems" but there is still two rows of images.

Comment: Ah, I see you fixed it, I was messing around with FireBug and after a refresh it was correct. What was the problem there? It's looking like you just removed those images? :P

Comment: Increased the value of the margin-bottom to 600px, it's a bit messy. I can't figure out what is causing these multiple rows :(

Answer (score 1):

use pixel Instead of % in width and height size ...

Answer (score 0):

Give a `position:relative;` value to the `.portfolio` elements and then try.

Comment: BTW, it seems you are doing something wrong. It's not necessary to give a percentage height value to the images. Just try this 

`.portfolio {width:80%;height:auto;}`

And percentage values are dependent on the view port and the available space in the container so the images might appear smaller if the viewport is less and same as what @evd told, IE have lots of bookmarks and other tools bars that can make your viewport smaller.

Comment: When I tried `.portfolio {width:80%;height:auto;}` the image were too small so I used .portfolio {height:88%;width:auto;} instead.